# How to make the stairways connected using geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am trying to create a stairway using an archimedian bezier curve. [image][image]

This is my node network
[image]

I am trying to perfectly align/size the individual steps to avoid the gaps inbetween as shown below. Can someone please help? Thanks in advance.[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe it would be better to generate the steps from the spiral, than to try to warp existing steps to shape? Maybe some variation on this.

Here's a group that converts a spiral to a block-staircase:

[image]

The strategy:

- Resample the spiral to the desired step-length
- Convert to mesh, split edges, scale each edge to 0 in Z about its bottom vertex
- Extrude edges radially to desired step-width
- Extrude resulting faces upward by the height of the split edges, before they were scaled.

The step-height is determined by step-length, and spiral height. The group can cope with spirals of varying radius. A couple of extra nodes, scaling the flattened edges along their length, could give you an overlap between the blocks.

[image]

[image]

**Edit:**

Following commentary, here's an adaptation of the group to work with an externally generated spiral:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. 

I too had tried that approach first. But it did not match my requirements of how the stairway should be fit in the overall model. Hence i had to use the curve object outside the geometry nodes.

Comment: Hi, @RMK !  See edit, for a first shot at the group, re-jigged to modify an externally- generated spiral. It does still assume the spiral is circular in XY, and up Z.

Comment: sorry for the delay in response. Yes, that works. Can you please tell as why you mentioned it needs to be circular in XY?. This is what i tried. https://i.stack.imgur.com/10VAq.png

Comment: Hi @RMK  It's just that the way the curve is sampled along its own length,  if the gradient is not constant-per-edge, you can get irregular step-heights.

Comment: Irregular step heights? Wow. That is exactly how i wanted. This was missing from my answer as it extruded by a constant height. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Although this is not a perfect solution, here is an update

[image]
[image]
[image]